# Interpolation of variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: linux, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, ksh

In the following script I am trying to interpolate value of i in Jenkinsfile.

```
host='10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2'
sh 'for i in $host; do echo \"$i\" ; \
sshpass -p root ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${i} \'echo "* * * * * script/test.ksh 6432 \${i} abc xyz" > /var/spool/cron/root\'; \
done'
```

It is printing the last ${i} on console however it interpolates first ${i} correctly. where i am doing wrong?

It prints like following on jenkins console

```
sshpass -p root ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.0.0.1 'echo " * * * * * scripts/test.ksh 6432 ${i} abc xyz" > /var/spool/cron/root'
```

Comment: Try removing escape slash from `\${i} abc xyz`.

Comment: Hi @SzymonStepniak,  It is printing same.

Comment: You opened Pandora's box of quoting :)

I think you should replace `...\'echo..."` with `..."echo...\'` and update all the following quotes. Also, consider triple quotes (`'''`) to enclose whole `sh` command and get rid of some backslashes.

Comment: @Tupteq you mean 
`sshpass -p root ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${i} "echo "* * * * * script/test.ksh 6432 \${i} abc xyz" > /var/spool/cron/root\";`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over a string containing values rather than over an array of values.

Plain shell (i.e. `/bin/sh`) might not be the easiest way round your problem. Nor do you need to harness awk, perl, python, or whatever. Simply use KornShell (`/bin/ksh` or `/usr/bin/ksh` depending on your UNIX environment). And you seem to be indeed creating a KornShell script (`test.ksh`).

I will be using `/bin/ksh` on macOS.

Turning your string is pretty simple now:

```
typeset host='10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2'
typeset -a hosts=( $host )
```

Now `hosts` is an array of items over which you can iterate. You can verity this by typing:

```
print -v hosts
```

Which will output:

```
(
    10.0.0.1
    10.0.0.2
)
```

You could simplify the above code, as below, but I recommend keeping to the above syntax:

```
host='10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2'
hosts=( $host )
```

So now we know how to access each host in your string. This answers your initial question. However I would recommend further modifications to avoid quoting and globing problems.

To do so I would recommend using a separate KornShell script, say `update-remote-crontabs.ksh` and invoking it as:

```
/path/to/update-remote-crontabs.ksh $host
```

The script's contents being:

```
#! /bin/ksh

typeset user=root
typeset host

for host in $@; do
    sshpass -p $user ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  $user@$host \
    $'echo \'* * * * * script/test.ksh 6432 '$host' abc xyz\' > /var/spool/cron/user'
done
```

Notice the use of `$'` to define an ANSI C string and `'$host'` to concatenate the `host` variable into our literal string.

Notice also that we haven't had to convert the original string into an array as this is done auto-magically by the interpreter when calling our script :-)

Last comment, `> /var/spool/cron/root` is, to my knowledge, bad practice. You should probably prefer something in the likes of:

```
(crontab -l; echo '* * * * * script/test.ksh 6432 '$host' abc xyz') | crontab -
```

Happy KornShell!